# How do I verify variables in lua?

Tags: variables, lua

I never programmed lua before, now I have to find a part in a script that generates a webinterface and verify a variable, so that it may only contain a valid hostname (only letters and the minus-sign)

How would I program this in lua?

Is there a simple manual, where to find such things (like [php.net](http://php.net) for PHP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `string.match(host,"^[%w%-]+$")~=nil`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a simple Lua manual, one exists over at the official page: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/

The resource linked by plalx explains the basics of lua pattern matching. So does: http://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html

Lpeg is a good pattern matching library: http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/

For a look at other pattern matching libraries, have a look at: http://lua-users.org/wiki/LibrariesAndBindings under the heading "Text Processing"

Answer (score 1):

I've never programmed in lua either, but it seems that it has a set of powerful pattern matching functions that you could use.

Just have a look at http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial

Comment: How can I use the match function in lua? I get the error: `attempt to call field `match' (a nil value)`

Comment: @rubo77: you should edit your original question with the extra details and what you are trying now. We can't guess whats going on without seeing your code.

Comment: @missingno Well he's probably trying to call `:match` on a table.

Comment: @dualed: Probably but its more helpful for future people if you put most things in the question instead of hiding them inside the comments. Stackoverflow is not a forum.